# RDS, AWS Lambda, App client - type of set up

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I've been racking my brain for days and can't find a solution.

I have an app written in python and want to use the variables which the user has input via text, png and checkbox in to a database but securely using AWS lambda instead of hard coding the db in to the app.

I've set up all the instances VPC with DBs inside them. I can create a deployment .py which can be invoked by the AWS lambda but how can I use the client to provide variables for this deployment? Or is there another way to do this?

Many thanks,

p.s the app also uses cognito for auth (using warrant).

Comment: I didn't get your question. Where does the sensitive info come from? Do you mean that passwords and connection strings are provided by users?

Comment: @ThalesMinussi yes the db config (I know I can probably hash them or similar)

Comment: If they're provided by the users it should be a no-brainer. Encrypt them before storing them in a database, fetch them during runtime and create the DB connection. Am I missing something here? If yes, I can elaborate an answer, but I don't see anything beyond the above

Comment: Depending on the type of RDS option, you could either use `IAM roles` for DB access or `AWS Secrets Manager`.

Comment: No maybe I think I'm confusing you. The app (client) connects to the database in which different users (who log in to the client using cognito) input their specific data in to corresponding tables.

Comment: @ASR yeah I can use IAM roles and use them as a security group for the VPC connection allowing them free access to the DB but I don't want to give the users IAM roles. Isn't the App (api or something) -> lambda -> rds route better than app (client) with IAM users -> RDS. In the latter i'd have to assign every user an IAM role

Comment: The `Lambda` (or any other service which is trying to access the DB) is assigned the `IAM role`, if the RDS flavor you are using supports it. Other way is `Secrets Manager`. But for both, I am assuming you are talking about `Lambda` access to the DB. Or do you want to control DB access from `Lambda` based on the user who is making the request?

Comment: @ASR I just want the client to be able to connect to the RDS without hard coding the login details for the DB as well as pass the input from the user in to the relevant tables. Yep, the AWS lambda has IAM role access to the RDS.

Comment: Sorry if I'm confusing you guys I think I'm confused myself

Comment: Why don't you look at `Secrets Manager` and see if that's what you need. It's quite simple & if you need help, message again.

Comment: @ASR ok i'll have a look at it

Comment: @ASR Secrets Manager seems like a really good viable option; the issue of security remains. If I leave the VPC open to all inbound connections (which to my knowledge it has to - unless I use IAM manager and a sec_group in the rule) it isn't secure. Although it isn't that much of an issue to be honest. Is there a way of using Cognito User pools as a security group for the VPC? Thanks again!

Comment: You can create an RDS security group which only accepts connections on the mysql/postgres port from the security group your lambda is in. Your RDS can be in a private subnet and the lambda in the public subnet of the VPC (though they both can be in the same subnet as well). I don't believe there is such a thing as using `User pools` as security group.

Comment: @ASR with the Secrets manager I wouldn't have to use a lambda for creds.. or are you saying using the lambda just for connection? I really appreciate the help/support from both of you. Which answer to tick as right lol

Comment: Lambda just for connecting to the DB. I have added details in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use `Secrets Manager` to *hide* DB connection info from your code. I setup RDS & secret manager using a `Cloudformation` script.

```
DBSecret:
Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
Properties:
  Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-${MasterUsername}'
  Description: DB secret
  GenerateSecretString:
    SecretStringTemplate: !Sub '{"username": "${MasterUsername}"}'
    GenerateStringKey: "password"
    PasswordLength: 16
    ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'

DBInstance:
Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
DependsOn: DBSecret
DeletionPolicy: Delete
Properties:
  DBInstanceClass: !FindInMap [InstanceSize, !Ref EnvironmentSize, DB]
  StorageType: !FindInMap [InstanceSize, !Ref EnvironmentSize, TYPE]
  AllocatedStorage: !FindInMap [InstanceSize, !Ref EnvironmentSize, STORAGE]
  AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: true
  AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !Ref AvailabilityZones ]
  BackupRetentionPeriod: !Ref BackupRetentionPeriod
  CopyTagsToSnapshot: false
  DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref AWS::StackName
  DBSnapshotIdentifier: !If [isRestore, !Ref SnapToRestore, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
  DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnets
  DeleteAutomatedBackups: true
  DeletionProtection: false
  EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication: false
  EnablePerformanceInsights: false
  Engine: postgres
  EngineVersion: 10.5
  MasterUsername: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref DBSecret, '::username}}' ]]
  MasterUserPassword: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref DBSecret, '::password}}' ]]
  MonitoringInterval: 0
  MultiAZ: !If [isMultiAZ, true, false]
  PreferredBackupWindow: '03:00-03:30'
  PreferredMaintenanceWindow: 'mon:04:00-mon:04:30'
  PubliclyAccessible: false
  StorageEncrypted: !If [isMicro, false, true]
  VPCSecurityGroups: !Ref VPCSecurityGroups

DBSecretAttachment:
Type: AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment
Properties:
  SecretId: !Ref DBSecret
  TargetId: !Ref DBInstance
  TargetType: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
```

The above script creates an RDS instance, a DB secret with all connection information. Please note the password is created by the script & stored in the secret.

Sample code in Nodejs to retrieve secret value with known secret id

```
const params = {
  SecretId: <secret id>, 
};
secretsmanager.getSecretValue(params, async function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
    else {
      console.log(data.SecretString);

      const data1= JSON.parse(data.SecretString);

      dbPort = data1.port;
      dbUsername = data1.username;
      dbPassword = data1.password;
      dbName = data1.dbname;
      dbEndpoint = data1.host;
    }
  });
```

Here's what your RDS security group should look like.

[image]
where source is the security group of your lambda.
Hope this helps.